# PHP slow log entry caused by mysqli_query() but nothing in mysql slow log

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

On a busy WP site, we're running a security plugin which creates an temporary lock entry in wp_options when dealing with potential attacks on the site (iThemes Security Pro) in the manner of:

```
$result = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
    "INSERT IGNORE INTO `$wpdb->options`
         (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`)
         VALUES (%s, %s, 'no') /* LOCK */",
                $lock, $release_at ) );
```

During occasional times when attacks are coming frequently, this causes entries in the PHP slow log along the lines of:

```
[08-Apr-2021 05:17:22]  [pool www] pid 69444
script_filename = /var/www/blog/index.php
[0x00007fc499214890] mysqli_query() /var/www/blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php:2056
[0x00007fc499214820] _do_query() /var/www/blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1945
[0x00007fc499214740] query() /var/www/blog/wp-content/plugins/ithemes-security-pro/core/lib.php:758
...etc
```

There is no entry in the mysql-slow log (which is enabled at 2 seconds along with log_queries_not_using_indexes) to suggest this is causing a slow query, but there's clearly a problem here. There's nothing about the query or the table that looks like it should cause a problem from what I can tell:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_options` (
  `option_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `option_name` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `option_value` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `autoload` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`),
  KEY `autoload` (`autoload`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=161904628 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
(Currently 700 records in the table)
```

It often corresponds with a period of time when all requests to the site end up 504ing because the apache threads are tied up waiting for these lock entries to clear (presumably). Error log shows such as:

```
[Thu Apr 08 05:17:25.952586 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 62595:tid 140674875750144] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client X.X.X.X:22504] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
```

I've not been able to catch this while it's happening but previously it's been leading to OOM Killer taking PHP down which has often crashed the server. The server instance has been made larger recently to try to avoid this and on the most recent occurance it did recover after about 20 minutes. But it remains a problem.

Server itself is a AWS t2.medium with 4GB RAM running a busy blog and a couple of quiet ones, and the DB is on a separate r6g.2xlarge with 64GB RAM and hosts a load of mySQL DBs for various in-house sites with no slow queries being reported for any of them, and no similar issues with slow PHP scripts. Just this one blog, just from this one plugin, with this one query.

Can anyone shed any light on what's happening here? Thanks

First edit:

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html
"If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index record is set. This use of a shared lock can result in deadlock should there be multiple sessions trying to insert the same row if another session already has an exclusive lock."

As the lock name is derived in the plugin from the type of attack, any logged-in user, and the source IP, it's possible that this is occurring.

Rather than using a SELECT to identify the existence of a lock record in wp_options and taking no action if found, it's using INSERT IGNORE INTO on each pass, so when an attacker is hitting the site quickly, perhaps this is causing the deadlock described on the mySQL link. I'll dig into this more but it may be an issue for the plugin support team.

Comment: Might be mysql releated - is slow query log enabled? Anything notable there longer than a long_query_time of < 1s. What is `show global status` as an SQL command? How much hardware are you running this on? Any apache error log messages?

Comment: @danblack - edited question to confirm slow query is enabled at 2 seconds along with log_queries_not_using_indexes, to include extract of apache error log showing php-fpm timeout (expected). SHOW GLOBAL STATUS gives a lot of output so what are you looking for here so I can post an extract or investigate more?

Comment: The slow query log captures queries that execute slowly, not the ones that wait for a lock to be cleared. Insert queries should not take for a long time to execute and inserts should not really tie up selects either - unless you are using blocking reads.

Comment: @Shadow - fair point on the slow queries, which led me to the noted in the edit. Blocking reads is not explicitly used, and from what I can tell the plugin isn't deliberately doing this, but it may end up that it's a plugin bug.

Comment: innodb status monitor can tell you more about recent deadlocks.

Comment: Lower to `long_query_time = 0.3` and add `log_slow_admin_statements = ON`.

Comment: What you have shown does not say whether the slowlog is ON, nor whether it is being written to a TABLE or FILE.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`

Comment: @RickJames - slow log time is arbitrary and 2 secs is a legacy carryover. As someone else pointed out, slow queries because of DB locks are not logged so this will not help with this issue, though at some point it would make sense to review slow log time. It doesn't look like admin statements are causing this, so can't see the point of enabling that, but didn't know that existed so thanks for bringing it to my attention. Slow logging is on and I thought that was evident from my OP, and is logged to file. I'll look into SHOW INNODB STATUS

Comment: @markdwhite - Slow queries are logged when they finish.  2 sec may be too high to catch much.

Comment: @RickJames - as I said, at some point I may well review the slow log time for general purposes, but the slow log will not be identifying long lock times with non-slow queries so right now, for this issue, the slow log only helps me by showing the the query itself is not the slow thing.

Comment: If you find that `wp_postmeta` is involved in slow queries, see this for some help:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: @RickJames The stack trace shows no evidence that this is being called after get_post() (or whatever it's called). It's all happening in the initialisation of WP.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you remove the security plugin?

Comment: @RickJames - the problem hasn't reoccurred since 8th, and though initially the plugin was disabled as very much seemed to be the cause, it's currently enabled and an issue has been raised with the plugin devs in case they can shed any light on this.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but its too long.

> which is enabled at 2 seconds along with log_queries_not_using_indexes

There's very little point in this. If you are interested in actually speeding up your database/reducing load then you need to log all queries and analyze the patterns of activity. Fixing a single query performance issue is likely to just push the problem elsewhere.

> It often corresponds with a period of time when all requests to the site end up 504ing

So given that you have *clear* evidence that PHP is overloaded and failing to execute scripts, why do you believe that the script containing your query is actually being invoked, AND executing the query AND that the query is taking longer than expected to run AND that the DBMS is not logging the fact?

> it's been leading to OOM Killer taking PHP down

Your server is misconfigured. It should be set up to limit the workload to the physical resources it can provide.

> which has often crashed the server

Yes, the OOM killer will have terminated at least one server process on the host. There is no "often" about it. Unless by "server" you are referring to the host - in which case, no it did not.

Wordpress is a lumbering dinosaur. That's completely the wrong place to put code intended to protect the dinosaur against attacks.

Comment: stack isn't really set up for discussion threads, so may have to respond in a few comments

The priority right now is finding and fixing the root cause of this single point of failure. Though the long terms of improving system responsiveness are always there, I'm not looking at speeding up/improving DB response as such. I understand your fundamental point, but have no wish to enable the general log unless it is the only way of resolving this issue.

Comment: PHP slow long indicates that the script is exceeding the slow limit during the execution of  mysqli_query(). This would indicate to me that this function is not returning in the expected timeframe, and reasons could include network issues, DB issues, and PHP processing issues. Given the slow log entries all refer to mysqli_query() it would suggest the latter is not the case. Network monitoring tools and continuing HTTP requests suggest it's not a network issue. So the finger gets pointed at mySQL in some way. What other possibilities do you see that I'm missing?

Comment: Previous webserver was misconfigured yes. Upgraded one is better.

Wordpress is a client requirement, as is this iThemes plugin. Fail2Ban also runs and we previously used that to detect brute-force login attempts on WP but stopped a while back.  I'll review that now.